# is there any solution for this problem? i have 3 tables customers, orders, payments and i want total bill and payment for each customer in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

query=>>

```
SELECT c_id,
       c_name, 
       c_contact, 
       SUM(o_quantity*o_price) AS bill, 
       SUM(p_total_payment) AS paid, 
       SUM((o_quantity*o_price)-(p_total_payment))
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN payments ON o_customer_id = p_customer_id 
LEFT JOIN customers ON o_customer_id = c_id
GROUP BY o_customer_id
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Join multiplying. You must aggregate separate tables then join.

Comment: And you typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Your starting table should be CUSTOMERS and you need to join the other 2 tables to it